# Bijection to isomorphism without normality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface. $Bl_p(S)$ be the blow up of $S$ at a point $P$. Let $Y$ be a variety. If we have: $f:Bl_p(S)\to Y$, $g:Y\to S$ such taht $f\circ g$ is the natural projection, and $f$ is a bijection, can we conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism?

I am aware that if given the extra condition that $Y$ is a normal variety, then the conclusion follows by a version of Zariski main theorem. See 
[Bijection implies isomorphism for algebraic varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264204/bijection-implies-isomorphism-for-algebraic-varieties)

Unfortunately, in my case $Y$ is some sort of moduli space whose normality is a little difficult to check.

Comment: That is not true.  You can "pinch" a tangent direction that is contained in the exceptional divisor.

Comment: @JasonStarr Could you explain a little more about how the pinching works? I am having trouble seeing what $f$ is in this case. Thank you!

Comment: In local coordinates $(x,y)$ on $\text{Bl}_p(S)$ where the morphism to $S$ is $(x,xy)$, define $Y$ to be $\text{Spec}\ A$ for the subring $A=k[x,xy,y^2,y^3]\subset k[x,y]$, i.e., $A\cong k[s,t,u,v]/\langle v^2-u^3, s^2u-t^2,sv-tu,s^3v-t^3\rangle.$

Comment: I just ran Macaulay2, and I missed one generator of that ideal: $su^2-tv.$